# Can´t run 192.168.45.34/cgi-bin/script.py from another pc

Tags: python

I can run my python script locally from console terminal, but when I try to run it from another pc I get Internal Server Error-500,

[image: Error from server]

This is the script

[image: this is the content of my script]

I tried to use os, commands and subprocess and it doesn´t work.
I also made the configurations of the CGI to work with python.
I also add this line to the sudoers file:

```
www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /path-to-script/xyz.py
```

I also changed permissions to make it executable.
Nothing Worked. Please Help

Comment: You should have a look in the server log to get details about the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are running everything with root privileges (`sudo`).  The web server you are using will not and should not have root permissions.

Do you actually need to use `sudo` with any of those commands?

Python, motion, and cp should not need to be run with `sudo`.